# Pandas - how to change cell according to next 10 cell's average

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that I am trying to clean up. The data is all numeric. Basically, if there is a cell that is below 0 or above 100 i want to set it to NaN. I solved this with this code:

```
    for col in df:
        df.loc[df[col] < 0, col] = numpy.NaN
        df.loc[df[col] > 100, col] = numpy.NaN
```

For values above 0 but below 20 i need to check the 10 cells above and below it. If the value is more than 20 different than the average of either the 10 cells in the same column above or below then it should also be set to numpy.NaN.

I am not sure how to go about this one quite yet, after reading the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) i know that i can simply pass in a function into the df.loc[] that returns a boolean list. However, I am not sure how to access the the passed in value's index to check for the 10 values above and below. I think it could look like something like this, but i am not even sure if this would properly produce a boolean list the way pd.df.loc[] wants it.

```
    def myFunc(value):
        #access index and create avgs for both tenBefore and tenAfter
        if abs(tenBeforeAvg - value) > 20 or abs(tenAfterAvg - value) > 20:
             return False
        else: 
             return True

    for col in df:
        df.loc[df[col] < 0, col] = numpy.NaN
        df.loc[df[col] > 100, col] = numpy.NaN
        df.loc[myFunc(df[col]), col] = numpy.NaN
```

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can help you on the way.

You can compare your `DataFrame` with a `rolling_mean` `DataFrame` and a reversed one for the averages above and below.
However, due to the `NaNs` in your dataframe, the average will not always be calculated, so you can ensure that it's calculated regardless using the `min_periods`.

Do check if it's accurate, as I haven't.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 110, (100, 3)))
#remove those higher than 100, lower than 0.
df[(df < 0) | (df > 100)] = np.nan
mean_desc = df.rolling(10, min_periods=1).mean()
mean_asc = df[::-1].rolling(10, min_periods=1).mean() # reversed rolling avg.
mean_asc.index = mean_desc.index
df[(df < 20) & (df > 0) & (df > mean_desc - 20) & (df < mean_desc + 20) & (df > mean_asc - 20) & (df < mean_asc + 20)] = "np.nan" # <-- replace with np.nan

print(df)
```